# Get lat and lon based on public IP with Google Geocode API?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I'm having the paid version of [Google Geocode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding). I was looking at their doc but I'm not sure. Is it possible as param to send my current public IP, and as a result to get the lat and long vaues?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation) for geolocation api from Ip Address
.